# jmeter - recording jbpm 6 ( kie-workbench) login page

Tags: java, jmeter, jbpm, jmeter-plugins, kie

Trying to record jbpm 6 ( kie-workbench) login page in Jmeter using recording controller and HTTP(s) test script recorder. After submitting valid username and password the application just stopping at "Please wait Loding application...." Refer following image

[Please wait Loding application.... and my proxy settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZJrO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

is the KIE Workbench hosted in your local environment? or in a remote machine? It might be the case that web sockets cannot connect so the application never load. Try using chrome and the chrome dev tools to see what is the problem.

Comment: Workbench is hosted in remote machine. getting same issue in chrome as well.

Comment: so it is probably a proxy settings and the web socket connection not being stablished

Comment: Salaboy- I need to perform some load testing using jmeter/other tool. I need to test the performance of the application when multiple human task requests executed like form Submit, claim, release etc. Kindly let me know which is the best way do load testing on jbpm 6 or share some more information regarding how i can proceed

Comment: Do you want to test the framework alone or the whole application?

Comment: Currently jbpm6 (jbpm-console) war file was deployed in tomcat. We are looking for testing framework as well as for the application. As a test engineer, i want to do performance testing for starting a process, assigning the tasks, listing the tasks and form submitting for human task. Please provide the input for the same